# Replacing Or with List

Tags: replacement, core-language

I'm having trouble with replacements involving `Or`. I think the trouble mainly comes from the fact that you can't simply replace `Or[a_] -> a`, since `a` is often an invalid expression (like `b, c`). I.e. `List[Or[a, b]] /. Or[a,b] -> a, b` gives an error.

I have expressions inside lists such as `{a, Or[b, c], d}` - but also expressions such as `{a, Or[b, c]}` etc. I want to find a good way to replace the `Or[a, b]` with `a, b` - this should be possible since everything is happening inside a list such that it is okay that `a, b` isn't a valid expression on its own. It will end up in something like `{x,a,b,z}`.

I have expressions like:

```
{{m[3]->0,mbar[3]->2},{m[3]->1,mbar[3]->1}||{m[3]->2,mbar[3]->0},id[1]}
```

Or in `FullForm`:

```
List[List[Rule[m[3],0],Rule[mbar[3],2]],Or[List[Rule[m[3],1],Rule[mbar[3],1]],List[Rule[m[3],2],Rule[mbar[3],0]]],id[1]]
```

What do you do with these annoying `Or`'s (which I get from `Solve/Reduce` and are thus forced upon me)?

I can find solutions for specific cases (`List[x_, Or[a_, b_], z_] -> List[x, a, b, z]`), but I would prefer a solution that does not involve looking at the precise structure of every object that involves `Or`. The whole point is that I need the replacements to work on things that get spit out by reduce without doing it by hand.

Note: The structure should not vary very wildly however. I expect no `Or`s inside `Or`s and only a combination of `List`s and `Rule`s and numbers.

Comment: Is `{{m[3] -> 0, 
   mbar[3] -> 2}, {m[3] -> 1, mbar[3] -> 1} || {m[3] -> 2, 
    mbar[3] -> 0}, id[1]} /. Or[a_, b_] :> Sequence @@ {a, b}` what you want?

Comment: `expression /. Or -> Sequence`

Comment: @corey979 yes, much more elegant :-)

Comment: @corey979 Yes great, thank you. I thought there had to be a simple way to do this. Thanks, I didn't know Sequence. What should I do now about the question? Is this question to pointless and  should I delete it? Or do you want to post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) to replace any `Head` with another. In combination with [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html):

```
{a, Or[b, c], d} /. Or -> Sequence
```

> {a, b, c, d}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Block` to temporarily set `Or` to `Sequence`:

```
exp = {{m[3] -> 0, mbar[3] -> 2}, 
       {m[3] -> 1, mbar[3] -> 1} || {m[3] -> 2, mbar[3] -> 0}, id[1]};

Block[{Or = Sequence}, exp]
```

> {{m[3] -> 0, mbar[3] -> 2}, {m[3] -> 1, mbar[3] -> 1}, {m[3] -> 2, 
>     mbar[3] -> 0}, id[1]}